# Creating a custom type on Youtrack

Tags: issue-tracking, youtrack

There are several types on Youtrack like ownedField[1], group[1] etc..

Is it possible to create a custom type which has custom fields like in ownedField has a Owned field linked to users?

[image: inserting a new owned field value]

We want to do it to apply a similar behavior to ownedField, where, when you select a Subsystem field (of type OwnedField), it "automatically" filled the issue's field Assignee with the user associated with that subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

To implement such behaviour you have to create WorkFlow that describes all appropriate actions.
Unfortunatelly, you will have to use WorkFlow Editor application to create WorkFlows and upload them to you YouTrack